# React, Nothing was returned from render

Tags: reactjs

I have this `Home` component:

```
import Items from './Items';
class Home extends Component{
  render(){
    const { items } = this.props;

    return(
      <div className="container">
          <Items items={items}/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And `Items` is this one:

```
import React from 'react';
const Items = (props) => {
    const { items } = props;
    items.map(item=>{
      return(
        <div>
            <p>{item.value}</p>
        </div>
      )
    });
};

export default Items;
```

I'm getting this error:

×
Error: Items(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Why? How can I return something if I need to map those `items` array.

Comment: You need to `return` the array returned by the `.map` method. Currently, the Items component doesn't return anything (only the map callback does)

Comment: `return items.map(item=>{`? wow, that works, yeah my mistake, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do return inside a `map()` (or any function that uses a callback), you need to add the extra return for the React component:

```
const Items = (props) => {

    const { items } = props;

    return items.map(item=>{
    ^^^^^^
      return(
        <div>
            <p>{item.value}</p>
        </div>
      )
    });
};
```

You can simplify the inner callback inside the `map()` by using regular parenthesis:

```
return items.map(item=> (
  <div>
     <p>{item.value}</p>
  </div>
));
```

This is called *implicit return* which works when there is no block scope `{ ... }` inside of arrow functions. So:

```
// These are all equivalent: return value is: [2,4]

[1,2].map(n => n * 2);
[1,2].map(n => (n * 2));
[1,2].map(n => { return (n * 2) });

// This, howover, will return [ undefined, undefined ] because
// there is no return inside the block-scope of the arrow function:

[1,2].map(n => { n * 2 });
```

Same with any kind of arrow function (such as the way you defined the `<Items>` component:

```
// This will work:

const Items = () => (
  items.map(item => ...)
);

// This will return undefined, and React won't like it:

const Items = () => {
  items.map(item => ...)
}
```

Hope the explanation makes sense and add any comment if something is unclear!

Finally, if you ever wished to not return anything from a render() or functional component, returning `null` will suffice:

```
  if (!props.items) {
    return null; // <-- this works
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I will use the => ()  instead two returns.

Comment: Glad I could help!